# I want to store json values in my android device

Tags: json

I want to store json values in my device. Because everytime application takes time to load json values. Instead of doing number of times to load, just want to load entire json values once. and without internet I can work with that. Once internet get connected, the application automatically load json values. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Database for that.

This way also you can store it.

```
Arraylist<ClassName> jsondata=new ArrayList<ClassName>
```

Here's an example:

```
public Class ClassName 
{

string fname;
string lname;

public void setfname(String fname)
{
this.fname=fname;
}

public void setlname(String lname)
{
this.lname=lname;
}

public String getlname(String lname)
{
return lname;
}

public String getfname(String fname)
{
return fname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to save the json in application's storage space.

code
/* save */

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("mydata", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.put("myjson", json.toString());
editor.commit();
```

/* restore */

```
JSONObject ret = null;
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("mydata", MODE_PRIVATE);
String jsonStr = pref.getString("myjson", null);
if (!TextUtil.isEmpty(jsonStr)) {
    ret = new JSONObject(jsonStr); // need try-catch
}
```

======

Do the restore every time the app is launching.

For the second part "Once internet get connected, the application automatically load json values."

You need to listen the network state change broadcast. When you get broadcast said the network (or wifi) is connected, grab the newest json from server, replace the json in the memory and save it to SharedPreferences